# How to sort data by two attribute types in timeAverage function

Tags: r, aggregate, average, plyr, openair

I have a dataset of bird locations and I would like to take a weekly average of these lat/long values, sorted by bird and by season.

Here is an example of the data:

```
datexample <- data.frame(
  "site" = c("A","B"), 
  "bird" = c("1A","2A"), 
  "date" = c("2017-07-15", "2017-07-15", "2017-07-30", "2017-07-30"),
  "season" = c("Fall","Winter"), 
  "lat" =  c(45.25, 44.75, 44.75, 44.75), 
  "lon" = c(-61.75, -61.25, -61.75, -61.25)
)
datexample
```

This is the code I currently have, which takes the mean lat/long for each bird, but does not sort it by season. I tried adding a second "type =" into the function, but this does not work.

```
library(openair)

datnew = timeAverage(datexample, avg.time = "week", statistic = "mean", type = "bird", interval = "season")
head(datnew)
```

I would like to have a weekly average of bird locations by bird and by season.

I am relatively new to R, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Parfait, it is from the package openair! Just added this into my question.

Comment: Why not just sort the data after this call?

Comment: @Parfait, I'm not sure what you mean by that. The output from this gives me an average lat/lon for each location in a table, but the table does not include the season. That attribute has somehow disappeared.